# GAE: Instance shutdown from source code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In user interface of Google App Engine, in "Instances" I can shutdown selected instances by press button "Shutdown".
Can I do shutdown by program from source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If can disable an entire application (from Application Settings page) for sometime and then reenable it (or you can delete it from that point onwards).

There is no way you can "shutdown" a particular instance. You can have different version of your application, but at any moment in time, you can only have only one instance as the active version of your application. You can however split traffic between different versions, but that does not change active versions.

In terms of performance, you can change the Max Idle Instances value to one so that only one of the instance is preloaded or active.

Comment: Even 1 instance it's to many for me. I want run application few times in day, but "Frontend Instance Hours" increase even my application doing nothing.

Comment: You can disable the application.

Comment: So, solution not exists for automatic or programmable shutdown instance. It's true?

Comment: yes. no there seems no way to automatic or programmable shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can force an instance to shutdown within your code, but it's not pretty.
Just allocate more memory than you instance has, it will be then shutdown for you.

I have used this technique in some python2.5 M/S apps where a DeadlineExceeded during startup could cause problems with incomplete imports.  If the next handled request gave me an ImportError somewhere I knew the instance was toast, so I would redirect the user to the site, and then create a really big string exhausting memory, and then that instance would be shutdown.

You could in theory do something similiar.